# How to override or perform min/max in python on your own class?

Tags: python, max, min

Not sure the best way to title this question, but how can I override or perform `min(a, b)` or `max(a, b)` on objects of a class i made?  I can override the `gt` and lt like below but I would like to override the min or max so that I'll be able to use something like `max(a, b, c ,d)`.  The class will have multiple property as well, but I think 2 for this example is sufficient.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, item1, item2):
        self.item1 = item1
        self.item2 = item2

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            if self.item1 > other.item1:
                return True
            elif self.item1 <= other.item1:
                return False
            elif self.item2 > other.item2:
                return True
            elif self.item2 <= other.item2:
                return False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            if self.item1 < other.item1:
                return True
            elif self.item1 >= other.item1:
                return False
            elif self.item2 < other.item2:
                return True
            elif self.item2 >= other.item2:
                return False
```

Ex:

```
a = MyClass(2,3)
b = MyClass(3,3)

print(a > b)
# False
```

I tried overriding `__cmp__` but that doesnt seem to work.

Would like to be able to do `max(a, b)` and return `b` object

Comment: You can already call `max(a, b, c, ...)` with an arbitrary number of arguments, and it'll return whichever is largest, by comparing them to each other. It uses `__gt__` and `__lt__` to do this, to the best of my knowledge. You can't override `max()` itself, unfortunately, because it's a built-in method and isn't bound to a specific class (though you could easily write your own method to do the same thing if you wanted). Is there a specific thing you want `max()` to do here that it doesn't do already, and if so could you give a clearer example?

Comment: (1) You are already returning `b` via `max(a, b)`.  `max(a, b) is b`

Comment: (2) Consider `functools.total_ordering`

Comment: (3) `max(a, b, c ,d)` is also already valid.  What specifically is wrong with what you've written now?

Comment: Im sorry, could have sworn it wasnt working right before.  But it does seem to work fine as is.  Thats so weird.  My bad, do i delete this question then? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Ah I remember now why it wasnt working before.  I used a = MyClass(3, 4) and b = MyClass(3, 2) and did min(a, b) and was returning 'a'.  The problem is because i have <= and >= for gt and lt respectively.

Comment: This appears to be working. Try `max(a,b)==b` which returns `True`

Comment: Don't forget the `return NotImplemented` for when the other object isn't an instance of the expected class.

Answer (score 5):

Just override the comparison magic methods.

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.value <= other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.value != other.value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other.value

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.value >= other.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

a = A(10)
b = A(20)
min(a, b)
```

Comment: is there a shorter version ?, is it enough to just define for ex `__le__()` and `__ge__()` to use max or min ?

Comment: Arrived here with your same question @Pablo, and there is functools.total_ordering for that (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering), leaving it here for future reference